# Problems cleaning up after cypress run

Tags: docker, npm, cypress

I'm executing cypress tests in mounted directory and I want to clean up after myself by deleting the node_modules:

```
npm uninstall
rm -rf node_modules
```

However, from time to time I'm getting errors:

> rm: cannot remove 'node_modules/.rxjs.DELETE/src/internal/scheduled':
> Directory not empty

All files in the volume have the owner nobody:nogroup, so my current user should be able to delete everything. From time to time it's not the case.

What I'm mising? How to correctly clean up after myself?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem before.

Apparently the message you have shown is also caused by files still being used in that directory (I know, misleading... It seems like `-rf` is just not working).

You mentioning that it works from time to time reinforces my suspicion, things like this are often timing related.

So what you could do is add a `sleep 5` or something to test that. The long-term solution should obviously look different... Just make sure, that everything is finished before attempting to clean stuff up.

Comment: You mean that cypress process returns, but there are still some threads doing cleanup in the background?